# How do market makers manage to sell a large number of shares at the end of a trading day without a significant reduction in their price?

Tags: trading, market-making

The trading day of May 9, 2019 was remarkable in this respect.

I have attached the Microsoft screenshot as an example, but I observed the same in many other securities.

[image]

Comment: As the market close approaches, the volume of trades per unit time increases. But this *does not represent selling pressure*. There are a lot of sellers who want to transact before the close, but there are also a lot of buyers who are also eager to get business done. So there is not necessarily an imbalance, or at least not any more than at any other time of day. There are more sellers **and** more buyers near the close (and also to a lesser extent near the open), that's all. And the market makers just stand in the middle, matching them up.

Comment: I did suppose that as the market close approaches, professional are rather inclined to get rid of stocks to avoid holding them overnight and risking.

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstood your question. Sorry.

Comment: But other professionals will have short positions they need to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that market makers that are long are inclined to get rid of stocks at the end of the day. But, market makers that are short are inclined to cover their shorts, maybe even more so.

So, if at the end of the day supply and demand is more or less balanced one would expect the overall position of the market makers to net out. Since, they all try to reduce their positions they are inclined to trade with each other as you noticed.

Comment: I supposed there is only one market maker per each stock

Comment: Aha, that’s definitely not the case for a stock such as Microsoft.

Comment: Anything else you'd like cleared up?

Comment: No, everything sounds reasonable.

Comment: Then please accept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Thank you @user3139228!